# Conditioning on List Sum

Tags: c#

**It gives an error when I say condition on issues.Sum. how can I do it?**

```
private async Task<CapabilityUtilizationPagedResultDto> GetCount(IEnumerable<CapabilityUtilizationDto> issues){
            
     var vfgrandtotal = issues.Sum(i => i.VFApprovedFinalEffort && i.SpecialRates=="test");
     var vfmd = vfgrandtotal / 19;
     return new CapabilityUtilizationPagedResultDto
                {
                    VFGrandTotal=vfgrandtotal,
                    VFMd=vfmd,
                    
                };
            }
```

Comment: And what is that error?

Comment: operator && cannot be applied to operands of type float and bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-7.0) does not accept filtering delegate, it has overloads accepting delegate to produce a number to sum over. Try something like (based on comment assuming you want to sum all `VFApprovedFinalEffort` where `SpecialRates` is equal to `test`):

```cs
 var vfgrandtotal = issues
    .Where(i => i.SpecialRates == "test")
    .Sum(i => i.VFApprovedFinalEffort /* or any other expression to sum over*/);
```